# Upload Facebook profile picture using FBSDKProfileExpressionKit - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fbsdk

I am trying to upload Facebook profile picture using `FBSDKProfileExpressionKit`.

I tried it as:

> 1. UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Small-mario"];
>      [FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromUIImage:img metadata:nil];
> 2. NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
>      [FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromData:data metadata:nil];

By using these two, I am redirected to the FB page but when I clicked the use button, the profile picture is not getting change.

Is there anything I am missing.

P.S. I already gone through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the facebook support team and get to know that this kit is no longer supported by them.